# Upgrade Python from 2.6 to 2.7 on Centos 6.5

Tags: linux, ssh, python

I want to update my Python version on server, my current Python version is 2.6 and I want upgrade it to 2.7. Plesk is installed in our server and I also have access to ssh.

**How can I upgrade it in Centos 6.5?**

I try below

Download Python and extract it

```
wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.8/Python-2.7.8.tar.xz  
xz -d Python-2.7.8.tar.xz  
tar -xvf Python-2.7.8.tar
```

Installation process

```
# Enter the directory:
cd Python-2.7.8

# Run the configure:
./configure --prefix=/usr/local

# compile and install it:
make  
make altinstall
# Checking Python version:
[root@nicetry ~]# python2.7 -V
Python 2.7.8  
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

but when I type `python --version` it returns `2.6.6`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't add comment yet, only answer:
Centos relies on python 2.6 for yum. You may break your system and yum if switching to 2.7 globally.

Comment: are you sure? I don't think so, do you have any source for what you tel ?

Comment: Maybe this will give you some hint what may happend:
[LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26269608/yum-is-broken-on-centos-6-2)

Comment: thanks for you attention,but after research I think yum have some problem with python 3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589971/yum-not-working

Comment: so can you tell me how can I install pyquery 1.2.4? I try pip install python-pyquery==1.2.4
 but getting error

Comment: Maybe this will help: pip install pyquery==1.2.4

Comment: I can confirm that you MUST NOT overwrite your /usr/bin/phyton file. I did it (CentOS 6.5), replacing 2.6.6 file with 2.7.14 one but it broke yum (and other packages, I guess). I needed to revert back, while keeping the "alongside" newer version I installed just the way OP did.

Comment: This was my worry as well.  i have broken yum before, so i can confirm that its easy to do, if you replace core yum.  Its a major distro core dependency. you may need a dual install, which is what im facing atm.

Answer (score 10):

Put the below line in `~/.bashrc` file:

```
alias python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

Now execute the command:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now type `python` to check which version it has mapped to. It maps to Python2.7.

Answer (score 0):

follow this link: https://ruter.github.io/2015/12/03/Update-python/
I did what it says and python is updated successfully. If you meet error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandler
```

just install openssl:

```
yum install openssl openssl-devel -y
```

BTW, centos uses yum, and yum uses 2.6 python, if you follow the link, you would have python2.6 moved to /usr/bin/python2.6, so in:

```
vim `which yum`
```

change `#!/usr/bin/python` to `#!/usr/bin/python2.6`

Answer (score -1):

You can't change `/usr/bin/python` without breaking your server.  Just use the one you installed to `/usr/local/bin/python2.7`, or switch to [IUS](https://ius.io) packages for python27 (which will install to `/usr/bin/python2.7`.  Either way, you need to leave `/usr/bin/python` alone.

Comment: Is this really still true? Python 2.6 was [EOL on October 2013](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2013-September/128287.html) and hasn't had security updates since then.

Comment: It's EOL upstream, but the packages in CentOS will be maintained with security fixes for the lifetime of each release (which matches the lifetime of the corresponding RHEL release).  That means that Python 2.4 (EL5) is "supported" until 2017-03, and Python 2.6 (EL6) is "supported" until 2020-11.

Answer (score -1):

It might be that python 2.7 got installed but you are supposed to use python2.7 for using that version.
Try checking `python2.7 --version`